# Is ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter necessary? It breaks my code when the sheet is protected, so can I safely omit it?

Tags: vba, excel

Upon activating a sheet I'm applying a filter based on a calculated column from the previous sheet.

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), LastCell).AutoFilter Field:=Range("filter").Column, Criteria1:="TRUE"

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
```

But is the second line at all necessary?  It seems to work alright without it, and the issue is that with the sheet protected, even with `activesheet.protect userinterfaceonly :=true`, `.applyfilter` is throwing up an error, whereas the autofilter line itself isn't.

I have no idea why this should be so, but anyway it seems to me the easiest solution is, if `.applyfilter` is unnecessary, omit it.

Comment: You could also unprotect the sheet, apply the filter, then re-protect the sheet. I'd think the fact that `.AutoFilter` works is only because of *how* sheet protection is configured; configured in other ways, that line would throw an error, too I think. Best remove as many assumptions as possible from the code.

Answer (score 1):

It is rarely necessary. Only if you had applied some `AutoFilter` then you invoked `Sheet1.ShowAllData`, which keep the filter "alive" but shows all the rows. So if you did that and you want to "re-apply" the active filter, you can then invoke `Sheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter`.

```
Sub Example()
  Sheet1.Range("A1:D20").AutoFilter 3, "x"
  Sheet1.ShowAllData              '<------ keeps filter alive but shows all data
  Sheet1.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter   '<------ applies "again" the same filter
End Sub
```

If you never use `ShowAllData` in your code, then I guarantee you that `ApplyFilter` is useless. In your code it obviously has no effect because you just place it immediately after the `AutoFilter` statement. So remove it and proceed.

Comment: Described behavior does not apply for `ListObject.AutoFilter` at least. If you use `ListObject.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` all properties of members of `AutoFIlter.Filters` are cleared.